# VPN software with dedicated IP addresses that i can switch back and forth between?

Tags: vpn

I am looking for a VPN software which will allow me to switch back and forth between many dedicated IP addresses.

For purposes of consistency, I would like to be able to switch back and forth seamlessly between the same several IP addresses - ideally canadian IP addresses.
Additionally, I would like to be able to add new IPs to this dedicated list quickly and simply.

Thanks.

Comment: Would be interesting. AFAIK most solutions are just 'pick a location' and you get an IP Address in that region. Might be easy to ask the VPN provider you fo with if they have an IP reservation for you, although this may defeat the purpose of 'private internet browsing'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Astrill has dedicated IP's as add-ons. You can pick any country. You can add them quickly and simply. Their software is great.

https://www.astrill.com/addons.php